# HANA SQL: CASE WHEN in DO BEGIN ... END statements

Tags: sql, hana

Does anyone know, how a CASE WHEN expression can be used in a DO BEGIN ... END statement?

Works:

```
WITH something_to_query_on AS (
SELECT 1 AS first_value, 2 AS second_value FROM dummy
UNION
SELECT 4 AS first_value, 3 AS second_value FROM dummy
)
SELECT first_value, second_value
, CASE WHEN first_value > second_value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS first_greater_second
FROM something_to_query_on
;
```

Works:

```
DO BEGIN
    something_to_query_on = SELECT 1 AS first_value, 2 AS second_value FROM dummy
                            UNION
                            SELECT 4 AS first_value, 3 AS second_value FROM dummy
                            ;
    
    SELECT first_value, second_value
    /*, CASE WHEN first_value > second_value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS first_greater_second*/
    FROM :something_to_query_on
    ;
END
```

Doesn't work:

```
DO BEGIN
    something_to_query_on = SELECT 1 AS first_value, 2 AS second_value FROM dummy
                            UNION
                            SELECT 4 AS first_value, 3 AS second_value FROM dummy
                            ;
    
    SELECT first_value, second_value
    , CASE WHEN first_value > second_value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS first_greater_second
    FROM :something_to_query_on
    ;
END
```

Error message:

```
SQL Error [257] [HY000]: SAP DBTech JDBC: [257] (at 329): sql syntax error: line 10 col 2 (at pos 329)
  SAP DBTech JDBC: [257] (at 329): sql syntax error: line 10 col 2 (at pos 329)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Tried and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After Reinis Verbelis answer I checked another IDE. Seems the Error only appears with DBeaver but not with HANA Modeler in Eclipse. Will make an issue at their Git Repo.